# how to display image from hard drive in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i want to Load image from hard disk and display in my flash movie i have little code when i click on button it open hyperlink so anybody know about image loading function

```
package{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite{

        public function Main():void{
            z_cst.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);    
            z_kp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);     
            z_kr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);   
            z_ka.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);   
            z_rs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);   
            z_c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);   
            z_vp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);  
            z_cr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);   
            z_cs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);   
        }

        private function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
            var url:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
            switch(e.target.name){
                case "z_cst": url.url="http://www.star.com"; break;
                case "z_kp": url.url="http://www.star.com"; break;
                case "z_kr": url.url="http://www.star.com"; break;
                case "z_ka": url.url="http://www.star.com"; break;
                case "z_rs": url.url="http://www.gear.com"; break;
                case "z_c": url.url="http://www.apple.com"; break;
                case "z_vp": url.url="http://www.images.com"; break;
                case "z_cr": url.url="http://www.buy.com"; break;
                case "z_cs": url.url="http://www.contact.com"; break;
            }
            navigateToURL(url,"_blank");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the Loader{} class for loading images - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

---

### Added some code - (wish code in comments could be formatted as code)

From your comment, it looks like you would have gotten it.  What you were missing was that you needed to call the Loader object's load() method and pass in the URLRequest object to it. Here is some code that does this loosely following your previous code:

```
private function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    this.addChild(loader);

    switch(e.target.name) {
        case "z_cst":
            loader.load(new URLRequest("/data/1.jpg"));
            break;
        case "z_kp":
            loader.load(new URLRequest("/data/2.jpg"));
            break;
        case "z_kr":
            loader.load(new URLRequest("/data/3.jpg"));
            break;
        default:
            trace("buttonClick() - No matching name found");
            this.removeChild(loader); // remove the Loader object from the stage as it is 'empty'
            break;
    }
}
```

I added the 'default' block to the switch block to help check for possible errors. A Loader object is a display object, so you can position it just like any other display object.

Comment: well i add Loader class to my code but confused i have not did action script coding before so please help little  i want to Load 1.jpg from image folder against button click whose instane name is z_cst          private function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader()    // make Loader object
    loader.load(request); 
    addChild(loader);
   switch(e.target.name){
    case "z_cst":
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/data/1.jpg");    // url request 
    break;

Comment: well there is little problem with your code on local hard drive you cant use /data/image.jpg     you have to give directly image name no sub folders your code will work on server but not local drive

Comment: You can have subfolders and still have it work locally. But in this case, I suspect it is that leading slash you have at the front (which makes flash start looking at the drive root locally?). Up on the server I believe the leading slash would make flash start looking for the file at the domain name root. I was just following your example of "/data/1.jpg" in your comment. =b